# Insertion sort with sentinel

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I would like to know if there is a purpose to add a sentinel to this code?

```
public void Sort(ArrayToSort<T> array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (array.isLess(j, j - 1)) {
                array.Swap(j, j - 1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the answer is yes, how should I do it? Cauz if I copy all the tab I'm pretty sure that's better to do without sentinel...
thanks ;)

Comment: I don't think there is a need to add any sentinel. Doesn't this piece of code work for you?

Comment: If you don't add the sentinel it will always keep searching until the start of the array, in the subloop. It will be functionally fine, but slower than it needs to be.

Comment: @devouredelysium, could you elaborate :) ? The subloop does have a break whenever it finds the correct position. So it won't probably go to the start of the array everytime unless and until the element is the smallest of all elements seen till now

Comment: Is this java pseudo-code or actual code? Java is not Javascript. `var` is not a keyword in Java. What is `Swap`? What is `isLess`? What is `ArrayToSort`? Also, both in Java and Javascript, it is `array.length` not `array.Length`

Comment: 1) the code works fine. Is just a complement question. 2) Update your sources @jrook, java 10 support keyword var. Swap is a swap method, isLess is a boolean method that compares two indexes and says if the first one is lower than the second one. And yeah, Lenght is a particularity of my teacher

Comment: Will you please provide fully qualified names for the methods you are using? Are they part of the standard library? The question is tagged `java` so a working Java code would help us understand the problem better.

Comment: And ArrayToSort is the array with generic type to sort haha. Anyway, my question is the algorithm, not java implementation. We should understand the snippet as pseudo code. Don't care about java

Comment: Yeah I kicked out the java tag. There is no problem, is a theoretical question if yes or not it makes sense to add a sentinel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way to make natural sentinel in insertion sort. Make the first traversal through the whole array, find the smallest element and shift it into the first position.

After that you get rid off index checking in inner loop. Example code for the second stage from Sedgewick book (Alg. in C):

```
for (i = l+2; i <= r; i++)
  { int j = i; Item v = a[i];
    while (less(v, a[j-1]))
      { a[j] = a[j-1]; j--; }
    a[j] = v;
  }
```

Also note that insertion sort uses element shifts, not swaps - for effectivity.

Using this method in the worst case you have about `n^2/2` **element comparison**s versus (`n^2/2` **element comparisons** + `n^2/2` i**ndex comparisons** in trivial case).

I believe that speed gain should exist, but it is not very large (element comparisons might be heavier, and there is also the same number of shift operations in both cases). You can profile both approaches and know result for your specific case.